# NotSerializableException on ViewScoped ManagedBean with CDI Injected properties

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to create a scalable JSF application.
I would like to save view states on client side but I have troubles with ViewScoped ManagedBean with CDI Injected attributes.

SomeService.java :

```
@Singleton
public class SomeService {
    // ...
}
```

SomeBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeBean implements Serializable {

            @Inject
            private SomeService someService;
}
```

Unfortunately glassfish fails to serialize `someService` which I don't want to be serializabled but re-injected.

I tried to make it transient which ends up to a NullPointerException when accessing `someService` after de-serialization.

What shall I do?

I'm aware that I could use CDI ViewScoped with Seam Faces or CODI but I want to minimize at most dependencies.

I could also wait for JEE7 which will provide @ViewScoped for CDI but we won't be using JEE7  before months.

**UPDATE** :
I just wanted to add that I was using embedded EJB bundled in a jar which is itself linked to my war.
NotSerializableException's stack trace has the following message :
`com.company.core.service.__EJB31_Generated__SomeService__Intf____Bean__`

Comment: Why are you injecting an EJB by CDI's `@Inject` instead of EJB's `@EJB`?

Comment: I don't really get the difference, according to [link](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/inject_vs_ejb) it's better to use `@EJB` in some cases. I tried to change from `@Inject` to `@EJB` without any improvement. Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like to self respond to my own questions but after some more research I found that it was a bug in Mojarra 2.1.6 (I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2) which is now solved in Mojarra 2.1.20.

To update Mojarra you just need to download a fresher version (eg: https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.20/javax.faces-2.1.20.jar) and place it in the $GLASSFISH/modules directory as javax.faces.jar.